# Condition on edittext to check firebase value or take user input

Tags: android

Hi friends I am fetching value from firebase and saving it to edittext (done that already). But I want to check if there is firebase value than put it on edittext else take input from user on the same edittext, because I am sending this value to another activity and there is error of null value if there is no value in firebase

Code I am trying is

```
      String  str= etext.getText().toString();

    if(str.equals("")) {

        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userId = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/Clients").child(userId);
        dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Paper.book().write(Common.channel, etext.getText().toString());
                names = dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue().toString();
                // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),names,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                etext.setText(names);
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userInput", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("username", names);
                editor.commit();


                Intent i = new Intent(Men.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: **take input from user on the same edittext** for this what you trying to do ??

Comment: Yes if there is no firebase value than take input from user.

Comment: But take input only if there is no firebase value.

Comment: what is happening right now ? where it is failing ?

Comment: It is taking Null value if there is no value in firebase. and giving error

Comment: who taking null value ? firebase ?? please add that piece of code

Comment: Sir code is already there the line above commented toast is taking null value in String names

Comment: It's hard to understand on which action firebase request get fired, is there any button or something ?

Comment: no it is oncreate method

Comment: if possible please add more code, entire activty class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178044/discussion-between-k132133-syed-arsalan-hussain-and-krishna-sharma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("channel_id") && dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue() != null) {
                    names = dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue().toString();
                    Paper.book().write(Common.channel, names);
                    etext.setText(names);
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("userInput", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", names);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Men.this, Main2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not working It is not going after this line while I am trying to debug 
names = dataSnapshot.child("channel_id").getValue().toString();

Comment: are you getting any exception ?? if name is not empty mean you are getting the value from firebase otherwise it will not do anything...

Comment: can you join me on chat